# noise/rpm/cpm values of 12V fan on 5V voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, fan

I am using Sunon HA40101V4-1000U-A99. This is 12V DC fan, but I am using it with 5V DC (according to specification). 
But I am not able to find values for audible noise, rpm, cpm, current on 5V. Datasheet just provides these values for 12V.

Is there any way how to find it out? Or to deduce it? 
I would like to get some table with values for specific voltages, how they are influenced (or at least for 5V in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the rpm with a tachometer, the cpm is the same as the rpm.
And what noise is it you are looking for ? physical noise or electrical noise. The physical you can just measure, with your phone.

Comment: You mean audible noise? Both noises are physical.

Comment: Yes, sorry, audible noise. I edited question.

Comment: Btw, I would like to get these values without any additional equipment. I hoped for some tables from producer (or formula to convert it)